# How to change launcher activity if app is not first time opened?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities, LoginActivity and MainActivity. I want to launcher LoginActivity if the app is first time opened, or launcher MainActivity if not. I have implemented with the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.activity_login);

    SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (pref.getBoolean("firstOpen", true)) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstOpen", false);
        editor.apply();

        // do some login work

        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        finish();
    }
}
```

But here is the question, the screen will blink, which is caused by calling startActivity. So is there any way I can eliminate this annoying transition?
Many thanks!

Comment: call this above `setContentView(R.id.activity_login);`

Comment: don't call this `setContentView(R.id.activity_login);` instead put this line below `if` condition. if it shows black screen for a second , try using default theme or some splash image. you can't change Launcher Activity

Comment: @Prashant Splash screen is good one .But user using only 2 activity

Comment: calling `setContentView(R.id.activity_login);` below `if` condition is not working for me, maybe I should try something about splash, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use SharedPreferences like this :

```
 if (pref.getBoolean("firstOpen", true) {
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
```

Comment: This is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setContentView(R.id.activity_login);` before checking for app opened first time.

try this way.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (pref.getBoolean("firstOpen", true)) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstOpen", false);
        editor.apply();

        // do some login work

        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        finish();
    }else{
        setContentView(R.id.activity_login);
    }
}
```